# Automize a set of tests one by one in makefile

Tags: makefile, ocaml

I have a project coded in OCaml, launched by a `makefile`. A part of `makefile` is as follows:

```
TESTS = t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10
$(TESTS): % : tests/%.ev        $(CMX_DOMAIN) analyze
                               ./analyze tests/$*.ev
```

So in a terminal, when I launch `make t1` for instance, it will first compile a binary (`analyze`), then run it with `t1.ev`.

Now, what I would like to set up is a mechanisme to test all the files in `TESTS` one by one. For instance, a command in a terminal `make alltests` compiles the binary, and then run it with `t1.ev`, `t2.ev`, etc.

Does anyone know how to realize it in `makefile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the simplest way would be to add a new target with the list of tests as prerequisites:

```
alltests: $(TESTS)
```